# Custom notification sound does not play when phone goes to sleep

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, push-notification

I am playing a custom notification sound when a Firebase notification of a particular kind is received. Basically, the path is specified in the payload and the .mp3 file is in the *resources/raw/* path of the Android platform folder as specified in the documentation.

The issue is that the custom notification sound always plays except for when I leave the phone to sleep **while the application is in the foreground**. In this case, it will play the default notification sound from the phone itself. If the phone is manually locked while the app is in the foreground, the custom notification sound plays fine. It only happens when I leave the phone to sleep on its own. Most importantly, the issue only happens on some phones (generally older models), for example; the **Samsung Galaxy J1 Mini**. The Android version on this phone is **5.1.1**.

I do not have any issues in the code or in the payload because this is happening only for when the phone sleeps **and** on certain phone models. I have not found any online sources that address this problem so I am hoping someone here has come across this before.

Comment: Are you using the newer FCM or older GCM?  Does the message contain a "data" payload, or a "notification" payload, or both?  Can you post any code in your app that executes when a FCM/GCM message is received?

Comment: `{
 "to": "deviceToken",
 "priority": "high",
 "notification": {
  "title": "Test title",
  "body": "Test message",
  "sound": "notification",
  "content_available": 1
 },
 "data": {
  "message": "Test message",
  "notifType": "typeCode",
  "bookingId": "Test ID"
 }
}`

This is what the payload looks like. The payload is being processed fine on the app. It is the notification .mp3 that is specified on the payload ("sound": "notification") that is not playing when the mobile goes to sleep and a notification is received.

Comment: When the wrong notification sound plays do you also receive a system tray notification with the message as specified in the payload?  Also, what version of the com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging library are you using in your app?  If it is not the latest version, is it an option to upgrade to the latest version (or at least some later version) and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes the system tray notification is received just fine including the message. I'm using cordova-plugin-firebase v0.1.23.

Comment: @edgaralienfoe Were you able to resolve this. .?

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening, it means GCM push messages aren't making it to your device. The most common reasons for this are:

1.You've disabled "background data" for Google Play Services in Android's system settings.

2.Check for your Application "background data" also.

3.Some Android Mobiles We are using Mobile Manager are like that.It'll stop running our application in background.So we have to allow our application running in background when mobile is locked.(For Whatsapp,Facebook App's mobile company automatically enable running the service in background).

4.If you are using any Theme launcher,You won't get any notification.

I followed these steps when I was facing this issue.

Comment: The GCM push messages actually arrive just fine and any related payload is processed correctly. It is the custom notification sound that is not playing, and instead, the default notification tone is playing. I repeat - this case is only happening when the aforementioned phone goes to sleep (not manually locked).